# Contextual version conflict error, Google colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to install and run sunpy on Google colab. It requires a package astropy version 3.1 or higher. Even after installing astropy version 3.2.1 when I import sunpy it gives the following error:

```
ContextualVersionConflict     Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-10-1a62dedba559> in <module>()
   ----> 1 import sunpy

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py in 
resolve(self, requirements, env, installer, replace_conflicting, 
extras)
789                 # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a 
dependency
790                 dependent_req = required_by[req]
--> 791                 raise VersionConflict(dist, 
req).with_context(dependent_req)
792 
793             # push the new requirements onto the stack

ContextualVersionConflict: (astropy 3.0.5 
(/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages), 
Requirement.parse('astropy>=3.1'), {'sunpy'})
```

pip list gives the following result:

```
Package                  Version              
------------------------ ---------------------
absl-py                  0.8.0                
aioftp                   0.13.0               
aiohttp                  3.6.1                
alabaster                0.7.12               
albumentations           0.1.12               
altair                   3.2.0                
astor                    0.8.0                
astropy                  3.2.1
```

How this can be resoloved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Install `astropy >= 3.1` by hand like so before sunpy:

```
!pip install astropy>=3.1
!pip install sunpy
```

Then, restart your runtime to pick up the new astropy using the Runtime -> Restart runtime menu. Finally, import sunpy.

Here's a worked example:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1741JFtJPq37S8oEzjzvANFWBbH3rQ4Oc

[image]

Comment: Note! Restart the kernel, otherwise, changes will not effect it.

Comment: You might not have to re-install, just restart the runtime after suntime has been installed. pip should remove the old version of astropy and install the new one as it installs sunpy. (I had the same problem with drizzle).

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried [restarting the Runtime/Kernel](https://github.com/mlco2/codecarbon/issues/112#issuecomment-773321626)? The error means that a new version has been installed of a Python package that was already loaded.

Comment: Thanks. In the situation I ran in to, I just needed to restart the runtime. In the pip3 install cell which I ran early on, it had already warned me that "***You must restart the runtime in order to use newly installed versions***", but I missed that message....