# How to resolve versionConflict error in Flask (PyJWT and Flask-JWT-Extended)

Tags: python, flask

I want to run a very simple application using `Flask` framework. I have also run and developed flask app before. After a while I need to develop a new simple app using it.

So I have created a virtual environment and activated it:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python --version # prints 3.8.6
pip --version # prints pip 20.3.1
```

Then installed `Flask`:

```
(venv) pip install -U Flask
```

Here is my `hello world` code:

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello, World!"
```

Whenever I run `flask run` command I face to the following error:

```
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (PyJWT 2.0.0 (/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('PyJWT<2.0,>=1.6.4'), {'Flask-JWT-Extended'})
```

I have also seen the similar links which I refer them below but I didn't get any clue about how resolving it.

[link1](https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/12849)
|
[link2](https://github.com/nipy/niwidgets/issues/57)
|
[link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58201636/contextual-version-conflict-error-google-colab)

**P.S** It is notable that I have tried installing different version of PyJWT like `1.7.1`, `2.0.0`, etc. but none of them worked properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the newest version of `Flask` (currently 2.0.1) has problem with dependencies.

The problem was resolved after downgrading it to `1.1.2` via the following command:

```sh
pip install Flask==1.1.2
```

Hope it will be fixed in near future!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to `pip install --upgrade flask-jwt-extended` as well. The newest version of that should work fine with `flask 2.x.x` and `PyJWT 2.x.x`.

**Versions:**

```
Flask==2.0.1
PyJWT==2.1.0
Flask_JWT_Extended==4.2.1
```

For more details you can checkout the following links:
[link1](https://gist.github.com/vimalloc/76058df977fcc814b7aff695e5ef398d)
| [link2](https://gist.github.com/vimalloc/fa3333a1f70454efd424031fdae96ab6)

Comment: I have tried this solution but it doesn't work properly. Would you please check it?

Comment: It seems to work fine on a fresh virtualenv for me. Check out https://gist.github.com/vimalloc/76058df977fcc814b7aff695e5ef398d and https://gist.github.com/vimalloc/fa3333a1f70454efd424031fdae96ab6 for a working example.

Comment: Thanks, would you please add `pip freeze` output to your answer for future readers?

Comment: Sure thing. I included the output in the first link.

Comment: Yeah, I have added to the post, if you can just review it!

Answer (score 0):

This solved my issue without having to make a new Venv/Environment from scratch :
try uninstalling Flask and all Flask Related modules and then just run
`pip install flask-jwt-extended` which will install flask properly again.

works with `flask-jwt-extended==4.3.1` and will setup `flask==2.0.2`