# ContextualVersionConflict: (PyYAML 5.3.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pyyaml>=5.4.1'), {'kubernetes'})

Tags: python, docker

`I am trying to install tutor on my Ubuntu v20 system. I went through the documentation and installed all the prerequisites such as Docker, docker copmpose and also started a proxy web server as stated in the documentation. I am getting the following message when I try to  run tutor locally

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (PyYAML 5.3.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pyyaml>=5.4.1'), {'kubernetes'})

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abhay/.local/bin/tutor", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3254, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3237, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3266, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 586, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 599, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (PyYAML 5.3.1 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('pyyaml>=5.4.1'), {'kubernetes'})
```

`

Answer (score 0):

It tells you that PyYAML version 5.4.1 and later is required, while you  have 5.3.1.

Try to install `pyyaml>=5.4.1`:

```
!pip install pyyaml>=5.4.1
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58201636/contextual-version-conflict-error-google-colab)